# Where are the other "algebra" tags besides "abstract" and "precalculus"?

Tags: discussion, tagging

If the "algebra" tag is declared heretical, as suggested [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6299/should-the-algebra-tag-be-blacklisted?cb=1), then what should one do with algebra questions for which neither the "abstract algebra" tag nor a "precalculus" tag is appropriate?

Comment: Could you give some examples?

Comment: @Noah, there has recently been a run on questions about discriminants of polynomials. I'm not comfortable with either the abstract-algebra tag or the algebra-precalculus tag for these. But maybe the "polynomials" tag would do.

Comment: (1) discriminants of polynomials; (2) How does one show that the product of two sums of squares of integers is a sum of squares in at least two different ways?; (3) How does one prove the Cayley--Hamilton theorem for real matrices?; (4) How does one use the singular-value decomposition in signal processing?; (5) Suppose $X$ is a $1000\times 2$ matrix of rank $2$ and you've shown that $X\hat\beta=X(X^T X)^{-1}X^T Y$.  How do you find a "left inverse" of the non-square matrix $X$ so that you can justify the left-cancellation that tells you that $\hat\beta=(X^T X)^{-1} X^T Y$? [to be continued]

Comment: .... (6) Does Euclid's algorithm for GCDs work with polynomials in three variables?

Comment: ...... (7) How does one prove?; and (8) How does one use, the Buckingham pi theorem?

Comment: .....(8) Is it true that if $c_1,c_2,c_3,\ldots$ is any sequence of scalars, there is exactly one sequence of polynomials $p_n(x)$, $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ such that for all $n$, $\deg p_n(x)=n$ and $p_n(x+y)=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} p_k(x)p_{n-k}(y)$ and $p_n\,'(0)=c_n$?

Comment: ....(9) Why does every shift-equivariant linear operator on the vector space of polynomials in $x$ map every polynomial $p(x)$ to a polynomials whose degree is $\le \deg p(x)$?

Comment: ....(10) Why is there a dot-product only in dimensions $3$ and $7$?

Comment: .....(11) What's the difference between an ordered pair of vectors and a tensor product of two vectors?

Comment: ....(12) How do you completely factor $x^n-1$ into polynomials with integer coefficients?

Comment: ....(13) For which $4$th-degree polynomials $p(y,x_1,\ldots,x_{14})$ is it true that $y$ is prime if and only if $\exists x_1,\ldots,x_{14}\in\mathbb Z\  p(y,x_1,\ldots,x_{14})=0$?

Comment: ....(14) Let $H_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n h_{n,k} x^k$ be the $n$th-degree Hermite polynomial and $B_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n b_{n,k} x^k$ the $n$th-degree Bernoulli polynomial.  Let $(H_n\circ B)(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n h_{n,k} b_k(x)$.  Define $B_n\circ H$ similarly.  How do you show that $B_n\circ H= H_n\circ B$, but that nothing similar happens with $H$ and $T$, where $T$ is the sequence of Chebyshev polynomials?

Comment: ....(15) Show that $\det\left[\gcd(i,j)\right]_{i,j=1}^n = \prod_{k=1}^n\varphi(k)$, where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function.

Comment: .....(16) Let $f$ be a polynomial of degree $d$.  Let $\Delta g(x) = g(x+1)-g(x)$.  Show that $f(n) = \sum_{k=0}^d (\Delta^k f)(0)\dbinom n k$.

Comment: .....(17) How was the solution by radicals to the general $4$th-degree equation first derived?

Comment: .....(18) Why is $\left[p\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)q(x)\right]_{x=0}$ a symmetric function of polynomials $p$ and $q$?

Comment: .....(19) How do you prove Sturm's theorem on the number of real zeros of a real polynomial in a specified bounded interval?

Comment: .......(20) Why is the sum of squares due to error plus the sum of squares due to regression equal to the total corrected sum of squares?

Comment: Michael, I'd say that (3), (5), possibly (9) could go linear-algebra; (1), (12), (17), (19) and maybe some others could be tagged "polynomials"; (2), (15) number-theory; (13) is logic; perhaps there's an "identities" tag that can be used, perhaps a commutative-algebra tag; it takes some imagination, but I suspect that for each of these there's a more informative tag than "algebra".

Comment: For (7) and [the first, as there are two] (8) we almost certainly should create a "dimensional-analysis" tag, and the "physics" tag would also be appropriate. (4) is obviously "linear-algebra" + "signal-processing", perhaps with a dose of "numerical-methods". (6) is perfectly fine for "abstract-algebra". (20) is good for some statistics tag + "error-propagation". (11) is good for "multilinear-algebra".

Comment: @Gerry: we may have to change the tag-wiki for "polynomials" a little bit to broaden its scope.

Comment: BTW, I have no idea what your item (10) is talking about, what do you mean exactly by "dot product" in that question? Do you mean instead "cross product"? In which case "geometric-algebra", "quaternions" and "octonions" seems to be good choices.

Comment: For 14: that's why there's [tag:orthogonal-polynomials]. It could also be tagged [tag:special-functions]. 20 will fall under [tag:statistics] and [tag:regression]. 17 could also have [tag:math-history] in addition to [tag:polynomials].

Comment: @WillieWong : That's a typo: I meant cross-product.

Comment: @J.M. : I'm not sure orthogonality is of the essence in #14.  The commutativity in question applies to any two Appell sequences, which are polynomial sequences satifying $f_n'(x)=nf_{n-1}(x)$.

Comment: I think at least some of my examples escape other tags.  The stuff about discriminants was already pointed out by Gerry Myerson: It's algebra, but it's not "abstract" (i.e. about which algebraic structures satisfy which axioms, etc.) nor "precalculus".

Answer (score 8):

Other "algebra" tags include [linear-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) (currently 4940 questions with this tag), [group-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-theory) (2555), [matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrices) (2200), [commutative-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commutative-algebra) (1363), [polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polynomials) (1164), [ring-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ring-theory) (998), [field-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-theory) (707), [vector-spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector-spaces) (634), [representation-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/representation-theory) (590), [finite-groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-groups) (579), [modules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modules) (466), [galois-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/galois-theory) (389), [eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eigenvalues) (361), [homological-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homological-algebra) (254), [finite-fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-fields) (241), [roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roots) (191), [abelian-groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abelian-groups) (187), [eigenvectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eigenvectors) (175), [determinant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/determinant) (172), [numerical-linear-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-linear-algebra) (171), [relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relations) (167), [boolean-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boolean-algebra) (165), and many, many more.

Comment: That's a good argument for removing the abstract-algebra tag.

Comment: I find this answer inadequate because what I really had in mind was just algebra with real or complex numbers that can be done by people who've never heard of groups, rings, etc., but that is far too advanced to qualify as pre-calculus and that at any rate would be inappropriate in a course preparing students for calculus.  Gerry Myerson mentioned some stuff about discriminants, and maybe that's the only good example mentioned here so far.  My hastily compiled list of examples was indeed hastily compiled.

Comment: Besides, many of these tags you list are topics included within what people call "abstract algebra", so that disqualifies them as examples of appropriate tags for things where "abstract algebra" is inappropriate.

Comment: Forgot to mention [tag:universal-algebra].

Answer (score -6):

On math.SE, “abstract algebra” is commonly used as a substitute for one of three things: [group-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-theory), [ring-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ring-theory), and [algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebras). Possibly many [boolean-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boolean-algebra) question also fall to this sinkhole. More specific tags as [polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polynomials) (pertain to algebras) and [field-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-theory) (pertains to ring theory) should be used as well, but a question tagged with **only** [abstract-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra) is something abnormal.

The whole “abstract algebra” umbrella (as well as its “algebra-precalculus” counterpart) seemingly originates from classification of educational courses in some countries, allegedly USA.

There is also such concept as [universal-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/universal-algebra), although questions tagged so at math.SE demonstrate significant pollution with not-really-universal things mentioned above.

Comment: A web search for "abstract algebra" will produce many textbooks, lecture notes, and course listings (in the USA and elsewhere) that have that title. The fact that *your* preferred terminology for this material is different does not render the term "abstract algebra" any less legitimate or correct.